# How to convert decimal to binary list in python

Tags: python, list, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert an integer to binary without using the built-in bin function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522773/convert-an-integer-to-binary-without-using-the-built-in-bin-function)

how do I convert a decimal number into a binary list.

For example, how do I change 8 into [1,0,0,0]

Comment: I tried this: 

binary = 0

while num != 0:
    bit = num % 2
    binary = bit +(10* binary)
    num = num / 2
binary=[binary]
return binary


but it doesn't give me commas between the numbers, and it doesn't always add the zeros.

Comment: What have you tried? You might want to look at the python docs for the function `bin`.

Comment: I want to do it without that function if I can

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522773/convert-an-integer-to-binary-without-using-the-built-in-bin-function) has already been asked.

Comment: @booboboobobob You should put such constraints in your question then.

Comment: @johnthexiii -- You're right.  Why not vote to close?

Comment: johnthexii you are no help at all. way to shut me down

Comment: @mgilson, I flagged it as an exact duplicate... should I have voted to close instead?

Comment: @johnthexiii -- See [this post on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91839/190459)

Comment: @mgilson, I will start doing that once I have the 3K rep, +1 thanks for the link.

Comment: @johnthexiii -- I couldn't remember how much rep was required for that.  Thanks for finding the duplicate.

Answer (score 31):

You can probably use the builtin `bin` function:

```
bin(8) #'0b1000'
```

to get the list:

```
[int(x) for x in bin(8)[2:]]
```

Although it seems like there's probably a better way...

Comment: Relying on string representation details and going from an integer to a string and then to a list seems....suboptimal.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
>>> list('{0:0b}'.format(8))
['1', '0', '0', '0']
```

Edit -- Ooops, you wanted integers:

```
>>> [int(x) for x in list('{0:0b}'.format(8))]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Another edit --

mgilson's version is a little bit faster:

```
$ python -m timeit "[int(x) for x in list('{0:0b}'.format(8))]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.37 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "[int(x) for x in bin(8)[2:]]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.26 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 7):

In the spirit of your original attempt:

```
binary = []
while num != 0:
    bit = num % 2
    binary.insert(0, bit)
    num = num / 2
```

Comment: Would be better to `.append()` the bits then `.reverse()` the list at the end rather than `insert`ing at the start of the list.